# A "surjective implies injective" property for endomorphism rings of modules

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, terminology

Fix a unital commutative ring $R$ and consider a left $R$-module $M$.
$\newcommand{\End}{{\rm End}}$

(For the indirect application I have in mind, which would require another post, $\End_R(M)$ will never be simple.)

Suppose the following is true:

> whenever $N$ is a left $R$-module and $\phi: \End_R(M)\to \End_R(N)$ is a surjective $R$-algebra homomorphism, then $\phi$ is injective.

(**edit:** thanks to Yves Cornulier for pointing out I should have said $N\neq 0$)

What can we say about $M$? In particular:

> Q1. What examples are there of $M$ which satisfy this property, which are not finitely generated as $R$-modules?

The condition being imposed here is reminiscent both of Hopfian rings and Hopfian modules, but at present I don't see a way to reduce the condition I'm considering to either of these notions.

> Q2. Is there an existing name for the condition I've just described above?

In my own rough notes I'm calling it "endo-Hopfian" but that seems unsatisfactory on several levels.

---

**Update:**
In comments, Jeremy Rickard has pointed out that when $R$ is a field and $M$ is an $R$-vector space of countably-infinite dimension then $M$ satisfies the requirements of Q1. In some sense this is related to the indirect application which motivates this question. However, in that (functional-analytic) setting, the right analogy would somehow be a ring $R$ which does not have global dimension zero. (In particular, in my setting not all epis in $R$-Mod split.) I still want $\End_R(M)$ non-simple.

Let me try to turn Q1 into a more specific but speculative/wild question:

> Q1b. If $M$ has the property described and is not finitely generated, and if $\End_R(M)$ is not simple, can we deduce anything about the (global) homological dimension of $R$? Or the homological dimension of $M$ in $R$-Mod?

It could be that the answer to Q1b is no for trivial reasons, in the sense that we can always cook up examples by extending a given $R$ in some way.

Comment: You parenthetically mention the extra condition that $\text{End}_R(M)$ is not simple. Do you want answers to Q1 to satisfy this condition? If not, there are examples like $R=\mathbb{Z}$, $M=\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: An example where ${\rm End}_R(M)$ is not simple is $R$ a field and $M$ a countable dimensional vector space.

Comment: By the way, “Hopfian” usually means that an epimorphism from the object *to itself* must be an isomorphism, which isn’t what you’re asking about. In particular, ${\rm End}_R(M)$ being Hopfian as an $R$-algebra doesn’t imply that $M$ satisfies your condition.

Comment: @JeremyRickard Oops - you're quite right. Well, I've changed the title to something less misleading, and edited the text a little. And yes, ideally I want examples where End_R(M) is non-simple, just to get a flavour for what may or may not be going on in the functional-analytic problem that motivates this question

Comment: @JeremyRickard Could you sketch how the argument in your example works? I understand why End_R(M) isn't simple in this case, and I think that the ideal of finite-rank R-linear maps is the unique non-trivial 2-sided ideal, but how do we rule out the possibility that the quotient by this ideal is End_R(N) for some N?

Comment: The quotient by the ideal is simple and infinite dimensional, but $\text{End}_R(N)$ is only simple when $N$ is finite dimensional (otherwise finite rank endomorphisms form an ideal).

Comment: If you’re interested in a variety of examples, maybe make the question community wiki?

Comment: @JeremyRickard I think Q2 in particular is after specifics, I didn't really want a shopping list as such. Thanks for clarifying the vector space example -- I was interested in checking the details because the analogous argument for Banach spaces and continuous endomorphisms (i.e. replace End_R(M) with B(X) ) can fail, this is something I have got my PhD student looking at right now :)

Comment: OK. It’s not a condition I remember seeing before, so I’m afraid I can’t help with Q2.

Comment: For Q1b you could just replace $R$ with $R[x]/(x^2)$ in my example, with $x$ annihilating $M$. Then $M$ has infinite projective dimension.